# Google App Engine Python simplejson escaping?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, simplejson

The version of django.utils.simplejson on GAE is for example escaping "/" characters, but not "\n" when doing `js = json.dumps(my_dict_w_strings_w_newline_and_slash)` which is causing problems when I try to `json.loads(js)` in my client someplace else.

Any suggestions on how to sort out a solution? The strings are base64 encoded data which get ruined by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague has suggested:

```python
if json.encoder.ESCAPE_DCT.get('/') != '/':
    json.encoder.ESCAPE_DCT['/'] = '/'
```

which is working nicely.

Answer (score 3):

I tried the simplejson version shipped with the SDK (Django 0.96 and 1.2) and both escape '\n':

```
>>> simplejson.dumps({'foo': '\n'})
'{"foo": "\\n"}'
```

And on http://shell.appspot.com/:

```
Google App Engine/1.5.1
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, Mar 17 2011, 15:16:30) 
[GCC 4.3.1]

>>> from django.utils import simplejson
>>> simplejson.dumps({'foo': '\n'})
'{"foo": "\\n"}'
>>> simplejson.dumps('foo/bar')
'"foo\\/bar"'
```

Comment: The actual version out on GAE isn't doing so. And the "/" is a bigger problem for me actually.

Comment: Hmm. Now I'm thinking maybe was `self.response.out.write` that was un-escaping the `\\/` to `\/` or something when I wanted just `/`.